# How to find an equation given the absolute value graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

my question is how can i get a equation out of this i have gathered the following

$$ y = a|x-h| + k$$

$$y = a|x-1| - 4$$ ($a$ i don't know yet and this is where i have a question)

to find $a$ can i just use any point in the graph and plug it in the equation or is their any other ways of doing it?

Comment: $a$ is the slope of the lines.

Comment: nitpick:  The lines have two different slopes.   a is the slope of the line when |x -h| is positive.

Comment: so what would i do to find A??

Answer (score 2):

This *is* $$y = a|x-1| - 4$$
your equation. It's a translation of the modulus function by 1 unit in the positive $x$ direction and by 4 units in the negative $y$ direction. The gradient is given by $a$.

You can see it's in the form $y=mx+c$ with $m=a$, $c=-4$ and $x=\mid x-1 \mid$ but this is the equation for a straight line.
However, the modulus takes two values, namely, $x-1$ and $1-x$, so there will be 2 straight line equations.

When dealing with modulus functions you must consider the two separate cases to find the component lines.

So the equation of the **left** line is $\color{blue}{y=a(1-x) -4}$ and the **right** line has equation $\color{red}{y=a(x-1) -4}$.

$a$ can be found by substituting in a point that lies on the left line; for example substitute $(-1,0)$ into the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ equation and solve for $a$:

$$\color{blue}{0=a(1--1) -4}$$
$$\implies \color{blue}{0=2a -4}$$
$$\implies \color{blue}{a=2}$$

Substituting $(3,0)$ into the $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ equation gives:
$$\color{red}{0=a(3-1) -4}$$
$$\implies \color{red}{0=2a -4}$$
$$\implies \color{red}{a=2}$$

as before.

Comment: so to find A i can use any point of the graph as long as the graph has gone trough it right?

Comment: @MATHASKER Correct, but choose the appropriate component equation

Comment: so the appropriate equation would be a(x-1)-4 right? and i have another question does this apply to any if given graph and asked to find the equation...if it is greatest equation graph?

Comment: @MATHASKER That's right, as long as the graph passes through that point you can substitute it in and solve it, I will show you that you can get the same answer for $a$ using the $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ equation as well.

Comment: @MATHASKER See my answer please, I have edited it to show you it can be done with either line (red or blue)

Comment: Ohh i see now thanks....I have an exam tommorow and i was thinking can i just plug in the point in lets say the first equation, the one with |x| in it. and if i get a negative inside these box || it means i have to turn it to positive right? will that effect the A?

Comment: @MATHASKER My best advice is separate them out into component equations first before you go substituting anything in (like i did here) and good luck with exam tomorrow!

Comment: @MATHASKER Is there anything else?

Comment: Thanks...and if i don't get the same a in both of the equation than that means something is wrong right?

Comment: @MATHASKER That's right, it will mean something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your equation $a=2$ to make the equation $y=2|x−1|−4$.

Verify this from the points: $(1, -4)$, $(3,0)$, and $(-1, 0)$.

$a$ is the slope of your equation.

Comment: how did you find A?

Comment: I took a few points where the x and y intersect and was able to guess.

Comment: The proper way to do it is to use the formula m = (y0 - y1)/(x0-x1)

Comment: For example, if you take (x0, y0) = (3,0) and (x0, y0) = (1,-4), then plugging in, m = (0-(-4))/(3-1) = 2

Comment: I would avoid taking points from different slopes. For example, don't use (-1, 0) and (1, -4) to find m because their slopes obviously not equal.

Comment: y0 x0? are they the x and y intercepts from each side of the graph?

Comment: Nah, it's just a point. Think of the first point having zero subscripts and the second point having 1 subscripts. It's the "slope formula."

Comment: ohh yes i remember the slope formula  thanks a lot for your answer...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion above. I meant (x0, y0) and (x1, y1), not the subscripts both being 0.